# Android: how to update progress bar taking user info?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android development. I have set the progress bar to 0. The plan is whenever the user gets a question right, the progress bar increments to 2. I take the user data from back4app.
I have set the max value for the progress bar to be 100.
I just need a frame to work with or some kind of guidelines on how to implement this progress bar. Any example code would be nice. I have this in my **fragment** outside of my onViewCreated method :/

```
public void setProgress() {
  userProgress.setProgress(0);
}
```

Comment: 1. Use a variable to track the progress value. 2. Increment the variable and call `setProgress()` on the progress bar to update it .

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it worked, do u know how to keep the value, it goes to 0 everytime I close the app

Answer (score 0):

Use  a counter variable , increment it when the user gets the question right , and then pass that counter variable to setProgress(int counter) function, and set it within  userProgress.setProgress(counter); .

Comment: Hi, Thank you it worked, do you know how to keep the value? When I close the app, the bar goes back to 0

Comment: @dermatologist There are multiple ways to persist a value when the app closes. One way is called `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I need help again, After I did the above code on progress bar, it only processes it once, then the progress bar stops incrementing, How can I make it so that I will increment every time the user gets the question right :/

Comment: @dermatologist call the setProgress() function everytime the user  gives a right answer.

Comment: @dermatologist Please post a new question